# Duplicate Layer Names shown on Arctoolbox

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have a python script that generates a polygon feature class file and it automatically displays the layer in the table of contents of ArcMap. So whenever I select the layer file in any Arctool as a input, it is showing me duplicate names of the layer. And also, whenever I remove the layer from ArcMap, the lock file of the shapefile doesn't get released unless I close ArcMap down. The code are as follows:

```
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outShapefile, shapefileName, "POLYGON", "",
                                "", "", spatial_reference)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(outLayer, shapefileName1)
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(shapefileName1, outLine_Layer)
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(shapefileName1, outLayer2, "ABSOLUTE")

addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(shapefileName1)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "TOP")
```

Do you have any idea why its doing this? The most frustrating part is that the locked file persist once the layer is removed from ArcMap.(20171109_2323.shp.SABBILGEDUMP.5028.13292.sr.lock)

Answer (score 1):

To remove the lock file, just call arcpy.Delete_management(layer) before the script terminates.
If you want to work with a layer file in Arcmap, try to access this layer from arcpy.mapping. It's not need to create a new layer file from the shapefile.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/"
arcpy.Delete_management("Myshp.shp")
fc= arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("D:/", "Myshp.shp", "POLYGON")
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
listLayer= arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
for l in listLayer:
    if l.name == "Myshp":
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management("Myshp","Mysymbology")
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("Myshp","D:/Loutput1.lyr","Absolute",None)
```

Without list layers :

```
import arcpy
    arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/"
    arcpy.Delete_management("Myshp.shp")
    fc= arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("D:/", "Myshp.shp", "POLYGON")
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management("Myshp","Mysymbology")
    arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("Myshp","D:/Loutput1.lyr","Absolute",None)
```

Comment: The arcpy.Delete_management() will not display the layer on ArcMap's table of contents

Comment: Do you create layer in-memory?

Comment: I edited my answer. I added a sample code.